# html hyperlink with hash in path address

Tags: html

I have create a outlook e-mail with a html body.

In the body of the e-mail I have inserted a hyperlink to a file. When clicking the link however it does not load the file.

I believe the issues is that the path where the file is saved contains a hash (#) in the folder name. I do not have permission to change the folder name. Is there anyway to get round this?

```
<td><a href='file:///H:MyTeamFolder/Folder#/'>"MyLinkName"</td>"
```

Comment: The `#` is harmless in most of the places. And in your case, it is perfectly safe.

Comment: When I click on the link in the e-mail it tells me it can't find the path 'H:MyTeamFolder/Folder' it seems to stop at the #?

Comment: Gotcha.. I thought it was the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
<td><a href='file:///H:MyTeamFolder/Folder%23/'>"MyLinkName"</td>"
```

you have to url-encode special characters in URLs ... # is %23.

The 'Hash' (#) Part orf URLs is not part of the location of the resource referred to by the url but rather a 'pointer' to an 'anchor' inside the resource. for file urls this means that it doesn't become part of the filename when you try to access that file via the url.

Answer (score 3):

`#` has a special meaning in URLs as the fragment separator. If you want to use a literal `#`, you need to URL-encode it to `%23`.

```
file:///H:MyTeamFolder/Folder%23/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> Replace **#** with  **%23**

Close 'a' tag properly . Final html should look like :

```
<td><a href='file:///H:MyTeamFolder/Folder%23/'>"MyLinkName" </a></td>
```